# Any way to find number of times PHP file was used by server?

Tags: php, apache, filesystems, zend-server

I'm working on an older server (PHP 5.2 Zend Server 5.0.4) where the previous developer sent the boss a csv file of all files used by the server (during browser requests) ordered by count, but I'm unable to find anything in the code or server config or anything that stores this or generates it, and not seeing any documentation about it.

Does PHP/Apache track this info anywhere?

Comment: It's almost certainly generated from the apache logs

Comment: I'm guessing you scan the logs to collate the information? I'm not seeing an option in any Apache interface or log file that shows totals.

Comment: Apache is a web server, with a capability to log what it serves; it isn't an analysis tool.... for that you can use standard Linux utilities such as grep, or other purpose built tools like [Apache Log Viewer](http://www.apacheviewer.com/)